# mySQL convert varchar to date

Tags: mysql

I need to convert a varchar value of 1/9/2011 to a date in mySQL and I want only the month and year.  So that I can then use the `PERIOD_DIFF` function (so I would need the above to be converted to 201101).

I've tried various ways using the `STR_TO_DATE` function:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CYOApp_oilChangedDate, '%m/%Y') FROM CYO_AppInfo
```

But I get weird results... (for example: 2009-01-00)

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
select date_format(str_to_date('31/12/2010', '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y%m');
```

or

```
select date_format(str_to_date('12/31/2011', '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y%m');
```

hard to tell from your example

Comment: this is perfect solution for string to date

Answer (score 4):

As gratitude to the timely help I got from here - a minor update to above.

```
$query = "UPDATE `db`.`table` SET `fieldname`=  str_to_date(  fieldname, '%d/%m/%Y')";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select  substring_index(your_column_name, '/', 1) years,
           substring_index(your_column_name, '/', -1) months,
           substring_index(substring_index(your_column_name, '/', 2),'/', -1) as dates
    from your_Table_Name;
```

Then just concat everything and you will have a proper set to work around with.