# SQL: convert from varchar to datetime and compare

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime, compare

I get an error when trying to compare a varchar field with an input from the user. The problem is that the input is a date and the field in the db is varchar. I believe i got to convert the db field (and input from user?) to datetime to be able to compare it, but i'm probably doing something wrong :(

The piece of sql that fails (part of a WHERE clause):

```
AND 
    CONVERT(datetime, bdo_report_item_field.content_text, 1) >= CONVERT(datetime, '01/10/2011', 1)
```

Error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'bdo_report_item_field.content_text, 1) >= CONVERT(datetime, '01/10/2011', 1))' at line 25

Really appriciate if someone can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think CONVERT is the function you need. I think you need to look at **str_to_date**.

Take a look at this question: [mySQL convert varchar to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706289/mysql-convert-varchar-to-date)

Comment: I agree convert() is SQL Server (only) function as far as I know

Answer (score 2):

CONVERT() does not accept three arguments:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert

... neither allows to specify the date format. It's more suitable to use STR_TO_DATE():

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Also, the data type of your GUI widget is not relevant at MySQL level since SQL queries are always strings.