# PHP between date doesn't match with the requested

Tags: php, sql, date, between

I have a question about between and join table.
I have a code below :

```
SELECT t_submissions.badge_id,
       t_submissions.employee_name,
       t_submissions.dept_name,
       t_submissions.ot_date,
       t_submissions.ot_from,
       t_submissions.ot_to,
       t_submissions.remarks,
       t_submissions.submission_by,
       t_acknowledged.acknowledge_by,
       t_approved.approval_by
FROM   t_submissions,
       t_acknowledged,
       t_approved
WHERE  ot_date BETWEEN '01-Mar-2012' AND '30-Mar-2012'
       AND t_submissions.submission_no = t_acknowledged.submission_no
       AND t_submissions.submission_no = t_approved.submission_no;
```

When I try compile this code, data with not date 01-Mar-2012 until 30-Mar-2012 show. Example data with date 01-Jun-2012, 02-Jul-2012, It show.
Well, I think something problem with my code. Need your suggestions. Please help. :-)

Comment: What datatype is your date fields in the table? String or datetime?

Comment: Hi... I using varchar data type...

Comment: I believe there is nothing related to PHP, only SQL (MySQL).

Comment: You have to set the datatype to `date` not varchar!

Comment: **Never ever** use `varchar` to store `date` in MySQL

Comment: try `'2012-03-01'` instead of `'01-Mar-2012'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the varchar to date and then compare. Here is a similar thread with solution.

[mySQL convert varchar to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706289/mysql-convert-varchar-to-date)

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments you have to convert the type of your date field to `date`. The comparison only works on `date`. And here is your code again. I tried beautifying it.
Also you should use the **numerical** representation of month in your dates.

```
SELECT ts.badge_id, ts.employee_name,
       ts.dept_name, ts.ot_date,
       ts.ot_from, ts.ot_to,
       ts.remarks, ts.submission_by,
       ta.acknowledge_by, tp.approval_by
FROM t_submissions AS ts, t_acknowledged AS ta, t_approved AS tp 
WHERE ot_date BETWEEN '01-03-2012' AND '30-03-2012' 
AND ts.submission_no = ta.submission_no 
AND ts.submission_no = tp.submission_no;
```