# how can i parse a string in sql in order to sort people depending on age?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

what I am trying to do is: sort people in database after date of birth (nvarchar, not date type) the date is in this string format: dd-MM-yyyy and by Sort, i mean return a list of all the people, but sorted after the date of birth, to Fill a datagridview.

data_nasterii = date of birth

what I tried is:

```
SELECT
[id], [specie], [sex], [data_nasterii], [greutate],
SUBSTRING(data_nasterii,6,4)  AS [an],
SUBSTRING(data_nasterii,3,2)  AS [luna],
SUBSTRING(data_nasterii,0,2)  AS [zi]
FROM
[animal]
WHERE
specie=@p1
ORDER BY
SUBSTRING(data_nasterii,6,4),
SUBSTRING(data_nasterii,3,2),
SUBSTRING(data_nasterii,0,2)
```

but this doesn't sort things right at all. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could [convert the string to a date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706289/mysql-convert-varchar-to-date), then sort based on that column.

Comment: Are you on mysql or sql server?

Comment: @rutter: not an option for me in this case. Mihai:sql server, in c# windows form

Comment: @Mihai the question has the MYSQL tag

Comment: could you please post a few of the records that you are getting to see the current behavior

Comment: it doesn't change a thing, just returns everything as it is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, what you're "doing wrong" is storing date values as strings, rather than `DATE` datatype.

Secondly, what you're doing wrong is not recognizing that `SUBSTRING` starts at offset 1, not 0.

So, `SUBSTRING(data_nasterii,6,4)` is returning `'-yyy'`.

Comment: I first tried using the DATE datatype in sql, but it was more complicated and couldn't get all the C# instructions to work. Thanks a lot spencer7593 for explaining the offset, it works perfectly now!! :)

Comment: and @spencer7593's mother probably intended to raise him to provide help while also deriding those asking for assistance