# Display mysql table sorted by date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an SQL table with a lot of data inside, and I have to display them in a webpage. You can find it [here](http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/other/european.php). By the way the data must be displayed in this way:

1. From the highest to the lowest VR (number that indicates the online points of this game)
2. People that reached 99,999 points must be displayed from the oldest to the newest date. Here you can see a picture as example:

[image]

My code works fine because the point 1 is satisfied, since the list goes from people with max points (99,999) to people with the minimum points (50,000). I have another problem.

I need to sort the people with 99,999 points looking at the date. In fact, if you look at the picture I have linked in point 2, the table on the right has the records (99,999) cronologically sorted but the table on the left has not.

```
<?php
$a=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","my_mk7vrlist");

$res= mysqli_query($a,"SELECT * FROM 0_vrs_europe ORDER BY `vrs` DESC, `date` DESC LIMIT 0 , 150");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
  {
   //here I print the rows of my html table
  }

mysqli_close($a);
?>
```

This is the code I have written for the table on the left, which is not cronologically sorted. In particular I thought about this:

```
ORDER BY `vrs` DESC, `date` DESC
```

With this code, the table is displayed in a decrescent order according with the vrs but people with 99,999 VR are not sorted in a correct cronological order. Could you help me?

The column with the date is a `varchar` in my table.

Comment: what column type is your date column? looks like varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you storing your dates? If you are saving them like strings, then order_by desc will not work. You will need to either save the values as a timestamp or convert them when you do the query.

See: [mySQL convert varchar to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706289/mysql-convert-varchar-to-date)

In order to do the select considering your string format, see the Specifier section in:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Assume your field name is called date.

```
select date_format(str_to_date(date, '%D %M %Y'), '%D %M %Y');
```

From the link I gave you:

```
%D  Day of the month with English suffix (0th, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, …)
%M  Month name (January..December)
%Y  Year, numeric, four digits
```

Comment: Yes sorry, I changed my answer

Answer (score 1):

Your date column is of the type `VARCHAR`, so MySQL treats it as a string and sorts it as such. If you want to sort by date you have to change the column type to `DATE` or `DATETIME`.

Comment: Will it work with the format I am using? For example "7th October 2013"

Comment: no, you will have to store it in 2013-10-07 format. you can reformat for the output with MySQL or PHP functions.

Comment: Actually it might. See the specifier section in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html