# MySQL convert Varchar to DateTime

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to convert MySQL varchar field in this format

```sql
"07/25/2002 16:15"
```

to correct MySQL datetime format

I tried the many variations of the `STR_TO_DATE` but still getting "Incorrect datetime value" errors.

Comment: Previously answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706289/mysql-convert-varchar-to-date

Comment: That question doesn't have time in it, just date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT STR_TO_DATE('07/25/2002 16:15','%m/%d/%Y %H:%i');`

returns

`2002-07-25 16:15:00`

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do it:

```
STR_TO_DATE(colname, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i')
```

Comment: I wonder how you missed this in your many variations? I just looked in the manual and copied all the formatting operators that matched your input.

Comment: Good question, I think it all started when I was reformatting and combining the fields from another table as the values were originally stored in two two different fields as "July 25 2005" and "10:35 PM". So first I converted the Date field to numbers and then added the time. Also added "-" where the space was just to change it to "/". Anyway, just got lost in my own stupidity for a minute. Thanks again for the help!