# Two different date types in column

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I am trying to create a age group array in mysql.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*),
    CASE 
        when age < 60 THEN '<60'
        when age >= 61 AND age <= 65 then '61-65'
        when age >= 66 AND age <= 70 then '66-70'
        when age >= 71 AND age <= 75 then '71-75'
        when age >= 76 AND age <= 80 then '76-80'
        when age > 81  then '>81'
    END as age_group

FROM( 
    SELECT YEAR(current_time()) - Year(DateBorn) AS age
    FROM custs
    WHERE  FDID = 'ANGL01'

) as custs2

GROUP BY age_group
```

When i ran this query, it worked fine, except that there were 2013 null results. It turns out that there are 2 data formats in the column.

The first on is just the year: 'yyyy'

The second on includes the day and month: 'dd/mm/yyyy'

How can I modify this query to take both data formats into account?

Comment: Is it a column datetime  type?

Comment: nope its a varchar :(

Comment: Fix your data/schema dont patch poor design and waste time

Comment: If I could upvote the same comment twice, I would.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706289/mysql-convert-varchar-to-date

Comment: @DrewPierce sometimes its impossible, i can not update the original sql server, only write queries

Comment: Sometimes you have to be the one wearing the trousers in the room

Comment: @Rob I feel your pain.  Legacy data is legacy data, and you can't always change it.

Comment: How many rows are in this table? How many separate chunks of code access table? Do you have rights to add a new col or two nullable?

Comment: BandAid queries didn't work yet?

Comment: I couldn't get anything to work, i ended up doing it in the code :(. I hate it so much, hopefully i will get around to fixing the SQL, but i have dead lines yo!

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should store dates using the `DATE` data type.

Given your current schema, assuming the dates are *always* either in yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy format then the year will always be the 4 rightmost characters, so you can use `RIGHT(DateBorn,4)`, like this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*),
    CASE 
        when age < 60 THEN '<60'
        when age >= 61 AND age <= 65 then '61-65'
        when age >= 66 AND age <= 70 then '66-70'
        when age >= 71 AND age <= 75 then '71-75'
        when age >= 76 AND age <= 80 then '76-80'
        when age > 81  then '>81'
    END as age_group
FROM( 
    SELECT YEAR(current_date()) - CAST(RIGHT(DateBorn,4) AS UNSIGNED)  AS age
    FROM custs
    WHERE  FDID = 'ANGL01'
) as custs2
GROUP BY age_group
```

You should check for values that don't match your expected date formats. A query like this will give you a sample of non-conformant rows:

```
select DateBorn
from custs 
where DateBorn not regexp '^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$'
and DateBorn not regexp '^[0-3][0-9]\/[0-1][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$'
limit 25
```

Comment: this looks amazing, but I'm getting 2785 null values now, i tried casting to int, but that gave me an error

Comment: That implies to me that some rows are in neither yyyy nor dd/mm/yyyy format. You should try `CAST(RIGHT(DateBorn,4) AS UNSIGNED)` to see if that fixes it. If not, check for other date formats.

Comment: Also make sure you are using `YEAR(current_date())` to get the current year. Your original code for that was wrong.

Comment: Thank you for all your help :), i got this error tho :( "BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(year(curdate()) - cast(right(`fps`.`custs`.`DateBorn`,4) as unsigned))'"

Comment: i am using current_date() even if the error says curdate()

Comment: Check for values that don't conform to your expected date formats. You can use the query I added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `DateBorn` is a text column, try this:

```
SELECT YEAR(now()) - Year(str_to_date(DateBorn,
    CASE WHEN char_length(DateBorn) = 4
    THEN '01/01/%Y'
    ELSE '%d/%m/%Y'
    END
)) AS age
```

Comment: im still getting the null results, it time format is dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: the yyyy values are now returning null, i tried to update the code, but i couldn't get anything to work

Answer (score 0):

How about MySQL's `STR_TO_DATE`?

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(YourField, '%d/%m/%Y'),'%Y')...
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Using this you can manipulate other occurrences.  I have inherited legacy data you cannot change, so this function will accommodate everything you can mask, if your data is fairly consistent.

I may have it backwards.  Try this, if needed.

SELECT date_format( str_to_date( dt3, '%m-%d-%Y' ) , '%m/%d/%Y' ) AS my_date FROM dt_tb3

http://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/date-string.php

Comment: because the date format is dd/mm/yyyy, str_to_date converts 23/06/32 to 2023-00-00

Answer (score 0):

[`current_time()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-time) is an alias for  [`curtime()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curtime) which returns `HH:MM:SS`. So `YEAR(current_time())` may result in some odd results. You might want to try `YEAR(NOW())` instead.

You would also want to use [`STR_TO_DATE(str,format)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to parse your varchar as a datetime. (Of course, it is better to fix the schema than patch it like this) Make sure to update the format as you have it in your table.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*),
    CASE 
        when age < 60 THEN '<60'
        when age >= 61 AND age <= 65 then '61-65'
        when age >= 66 AND age <= 70 then '66-70'
        when age >= 71 AND age <= 75 then '71-75'
        when age >= 76 AND age <= 80 then '76-80'
        when age > 81  then '>81'
    END as age_group

FROM( 
    SELECT YEAR(NOW()) - Year(str_to_date(DateBorn, '%d/%m/%Y')) AS age
    FROM custs
    WHERE  FDID = 'ANGL01'

) as custs2

GROUP BY age_group
```