# Get results order by date in MySQL if date field's datatype is varchar

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get results ordered by date from a table in mysql but the problem is the date column's datatype is `varhcar`

Here is the table structure:

```
-------------------------------------------
ID        EVENT                        DATE
-------------------------------------------
1         My Wife’s Birthday     23-02-1987
2         Wedding Anniversary    18-05-2006
3         My Son’s Birthday      06-12-2014
4         Ramadan                08-06-2016
-------------------------------------------
INT       VARCHAR                   VARCHAR
```

Here is the query `SELECT event_date FROM events ORDER BY CONVERT(event_date, DATETIME)`

Im using `CONVERT` but I think I'm doing it wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: Why not change to column type to date?

Comment: If I can then I will not be posting my question here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mySQL convert varchar to date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706289/mysql-convert-varchar-to-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function

```
order by str_to_date(`DATE`, '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: Thanks Man! I have tried it earlier but was doing something wrong

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If we need in ascending order

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER by DATE ASC
```

If we need in descending order

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER by DATE DESC
```