# format table with varchar date format to date mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a database with multiple tables using date fields.

Some of them have this format as `varchar(10)` `dd-mm-yyyy` and other have a mix of `dd-mm-yyyy` and `yyyy-mm-dd`.

I tried changing the format of the fields to `DATE`, however, everything in `dd-mm-yyyy` turn into `0000-00-00`

**There is a correct way turn all varchars as date type and only dd-mm-yyyy into DATE format in the tale with mixed date formats before change the field type?**

```
date
--------
01-12-2015 *** change this
05-11-2016 *** this
01-04-2016 ***  and this
2016-05-11 +++ and keep the ones on this format
```

Comment: `UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
SET COMUMN_NAME = str_to_date( COMUMN_NAME, '%Y-%m-%d' );`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mySQL convert varchar to date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706289/mysql-convert-varchar-to-date)

Comment: If you're using a programming language you can easily do that...  For example (in PHP), `$newField = new date('Y-m-d', $oldField)`, then update the record.

Comment: but if the field is mixed between data in the correct format and dd-mm-yyyy, how to update only the ones that are on dd-mm-yyyy?

Comment: Only update if the first 4 characters aren't all digits

Comment: It changes the dates to a 2030 year

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `table` 
SET `Fecha`=date_format(str_to_date(`Datefield`, '%d-%m-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') 
WHERE date_format(str_to_date(`Datefield`, '%d-%m-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') IS NOT NULL
```

This worked properly