# How do i format different formats of date in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to format

```
1/2/55
05/06/82
9-15-58
2/12/65
02-17-1967
2007-06-12
04/29/197
```

dates in to MM/DD/YYYY. these are in varchar now. need to format and convert in to date. Any help please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert a string to date in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201383/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-mysql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mySQL convert varchar to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706289/mysql-convert-varchar-to-date)

Answer (score 1):

You use mysql DATE_FORMAT() method.
Link: 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html