# How to convert varchar data type into datetime data type without data lose

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
my query(select invoice_date from pr_tax_intra where invoice_date between '03-05-2018' and '05-05-2018')
```

invoice_date data type varchar->(invoice_date   varchar(55) )

output images:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkGm0.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skyWB.png) This images select only 5 month data but show in 4&5  month  data also ...

i am using mysql database

i have stored date as varchar(255) data type and Date format is dd/MM/yyyy now i have to convert it into date data type can u help me in query ?

i have 780 records and each recod contain the Date in format of dd/MM/YYYY but due to varchar data type i can not perform calculation on Date so i have to convert into date without data lose.

please help me

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: mysql database(phpmyadmin)

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to convert whole column into datetime first?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mySQL convert varchar to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706289/mysql-convert-varchar-to-date)

Comment: Take a backup. Add a new date column, copy/convert data from varchar column. Drop varchar column. Rename new column. Hope no view/fk/stored procedure dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can use myqsl STR_TO_DATE() function

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("10 August 2017", "%d %M %Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

//For Testing

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('21/05/2018', '%Y/%m/%d') 
 ,'%d/%m/%Y')
```

In your case use below query

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(YourVarcharDateColumn, '%Y/%m/%d') 
 ,'%d/%m/%Y') from YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this,
get all your record and then apply a while loop

```
$ListContent = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `date_filed` FROM table_name") or die(mysqli_error($conn)." Error in query"); // $conn is connection object
while($arr = mysqli_fetch_array($ListContent)){
    $currentDate    =   $arr['date_filed'];
    $currentRowID   =   $arr['id']; // Unique id column name
    $newDate    =   date("Y-m-d", strtotime($currentDate)); 

    $sqlUpdate  =   "Update table_name SET `date_filed` ='".$newDate."' WHERE id=".$currentRowID;

    mysqli_query($conn, $sqlUpdate) or die(mysqli_error($conn)." Error in update query");


}
```

This will make your all record in "yyyy-mm-dd" format and then change your field into date type

Answer (score -1):

SQL Server (MSSQL)

```
SELECT FORMAT(YourDateColumn,'dd-MM-yyyy') from yourTable
```

Comment: Not useful when the OP is using MySQL.