# Converting a varchar datatype to date in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

While defining the database i have a column name called 'date_posted' for which i dont know why i used varchar datatype. I now need to get all the posts which are less than 10 days old .However I now have lots of data so changing the structure might create a problem. Is there any way to convert varchat into data in php code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mySQL convert varchar to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706289/mysql-convert-varchar-to-date)

Comment: @Swati .. No its different

Comment: You haven't described what your data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

**try this in your query**

```
select date_format(str_to_date('02/28/2019', '%m/%d/%Y'), '%m/%d/%Y');
```

Comment: refer these two links [https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp] [https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp] so you understand it better

Answer (score 0):

Use This code:

SELECT STR_TO_DATE('DATE_IN_STRING',"%M %d %Y");