# MySQL: How to set a DATE column by converting all values in a VARCHAR column?

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which there is a column called "DATE" which contains dates in the format "23-Nov-2017" as datatype VARCHAR. I'm trying to convert this VARCHAR column and store it in a new column called "NEWDATE" of datatype DATE.

I have created the new column "NEWDATE" of type DATE and I am trying to use the STR_TO_DATE() function to perform the conversion. However, I can't get it to work for some reason.

```
UPDATE table SET NEWDATE = STR_TO_DATE(DATE,'%d-%m-%Y');
```

The NEWDATE column is not updated with any values after the statement. I guess this means that the statement does not execute. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I have also tried STR_TO_DATE(DATE,'%d-%b-%Y'). However there is still no change to the values in the NEWDATE column

Comment: maybe here you can find an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706289/mysql-convert-varchar-to-date

Comment: You should read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Your format `'%d-%m-%Y'` does not match your actual date string !!!!!

Comment: 'Scanning starts at the beginning of str and fails if format is found not to match' - so I guess your data does not look like you think it does.

Comment: @P.Salmon how do I find out if it isn't? I copy pasted one of the values to check if there are any additional spaces/unseen characters etc. That doesn't seem to be the case though

Comment: If you have dirty data then it's going to be a slog finding it. you could try a select str_to_data binary chopping through the table in an attempt to find problems. You could try the conversion if the the time field is not null. You could test that every time contains a valid abbreviated month string etc = You get the idea not simple or quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format '%d-%m-%Y' does not match your actual date string  "23-Nov-2017"

The `%m` is for numeric month and you have an abbreviated text month
Use `%b` for 3 char month values like this:

```
STR_TO_DATE(DATE,'%d-%b-%Y')
```

EDIT: WorkBench issue

That is just a Workbench config setting to stop you accidentally issuing a HUGE update. You can either turn that setting OFF or frig it a bit by giving it a WHERE clause that will allow it to run like below. Below assumes this table has an `id` column

```
UPDATE table SET NEWDATE = STR_TO_DATE(DATE,'%d-%b-%Y') WHERE id<10000000;
```

Or

```
UPDATE table SET NEWDATE = STR_TO_DATE(DATE,'%d-%b-%Y') WHERE id>0;
```

Comment: I did try this as well. The same thing happens, there is no change to the column.

Comment: Hmmm then something else is getting in the way

Comment: Any other ideas? I could provide you with more information if required

Comment: I would first check that all your text dates have that format. But even if some are not in this format the one's that are should have the update applied to them.

Comment: How are you running this query, I mean are you using a tool like MySQL WorkBench or phpMyAdmin or a programming language

Comment: I'm using MySQL WorkBench

Comment: So what messages does it give you when you run this query. In the `OUTPUT` section

Comment: Message: Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.  To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect. 0.000 sec

I didn't check this! So should I turn off safe update or should I enter a command with a ```WHERE``` clause?

Comment: I had a funny feeling it was going to be that. **See the answer** I added something new