# Date format issue for current month

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Date formt in my database is `dd/mm/yyyy`.I am having dates `02/01/2019, 02/03/2019, 07/05/2019`. I stored them in `varchar`. (I cannot use date format as my whole project will mess up.)

In this i just wan only dates of current month
EG:

```
$currentMonth = date('m'); 
$receipt = DB::table('receipt_payment')
    ->whereRaw('MONTH(due_date) = ?', [$xcurrentMonth])
    ->get();
```

But I am getting `count()==0`

Comment: then, the first thing should be done is transferring those data into a date column.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mySQL convert varchar to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706289/mysql-convert-varchar-to-date)

Comment: _"I cannot use date format as my whole project will mess up"_ - Then I would seriously consider refactoring the code so it can handle using a proper date column in the database.

Comment: Actually your current code is messed-up. using `date` or `dateTime`column will actually correct it.

Comment: `I cannot use date format as my whole project will mess up.` this simply means the overall architecture is bad (from both database and code point of view). I'd consider rewriting such code. The thing with your query is... you can still do that, but if you'd use proper data type for storing dates (or maybe you'd want to use int for months), your query would be MUCH faster compared to what it will be if you use conversion from a string to month number.

Comment: try running your query in MySQL first and check what you suppose to get and data your getting currently.

Comment: you have to use month and year both

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can try converting string to date in mysql.

You can use [str_to_date()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

For reference https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

```
$currentMonth = date('m'); 
$receipt = DB::table('receipt_payment')
    ->whereRaw('MONTH(str_to_date(due_date , '%m/%d/%Y')) = ?', [$xcurrentMonth])
    ->get();
```

Hope this helps