# MySQL insert into by select formatted columns query

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I am on MySQL 8.0 .
I have source and target tables

```
   {
      id PKEY,
      date_time varchar(100)
    }
```

```
{ id PKEY,
  date_time DATETIME,
 }
```

I need to copy source table into target table.
The source table's date_time column has datetime strings something like this
`2020-03-06 10:10:10.408-05`
with a timezone offset.

This is the query I am running and it just does not work.

```
   insert into target (id,date_time) 
   select id,DATE_FORMAT(date_time,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') from source
```

I get an error saying Data truncated.

*SQL Error [1292] [22001]: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2020-03-06 06:23:17.408-05'
  Data truncation: Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2020-10-10 06:23:17.408-05'*
I tried replacing DATE_FORMAT with STR_TO_DATE

```
   insert into target (id,date_time) 
   select id,STR_TO_DATE(date_time,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') from source
```

Still the same result
Why is it trying to insert unformatted date_time into target table ?

---

**ANSWER :**
The problems seems like the STR_TO_DATE or DATE_FORMAT functions are unable to parse '408-05' part of the timestamp. So , I created a temp column date_time_no_tz and set the values like this.

```
update source
SET date_time_no_tz = DATE_FORMAT(LEFT(date_time, LENGTH(date_time)-3), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s');
```

Now I had the right datetime column values and I dropped the old column and renamed date_time_no_tz to date_time. 
May be this formatting may work with INSERT query as well. Haven't tried.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mySQL convert varchar to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706289/mysql-convert-varchar-to-date)

Comment: You should be using `STR_TO_DATE`, not `DATE_FORMAT`

Comment: This works for SELECT statements. But when it comes to inserting selected values into table like mentioned above , I get this same error