# Convert a column of varchar dates in mm-dd-yyyy into a column with Date datatype

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table in a csv file with date format MM-DD-YYYY. I will like to import the whole table into mysql. To do so, I believe I will need to create a table first. Since I am unable to import that table because of the date format not being recognized by SQL, I created the field as a varchar field.

Now that I have imported the table in, I will like to convert this varchar column into a date column (YYYY-MM-DD) that I can run operations on (such as using the YEAR() function). Can someone teach me how? I am new to SQL.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mySQL convert varchar to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706289/mysql-convert-varchar-to-date)

Answer (score 0):

If you "import CSV into MySQL" then you use LOAD DATA INFILE.

If your CSV contains date column in a format which is not recognized by MySQL then you must use SET-variant of LOAD DATA INFILE query.

```sql
CREATE TABLE imported__from_csv ( .. ,
                                  datetime_column DATETIME, 
                                  .. );
```

```sql
LOAD DATA ..
INFILE .. 
INTO TABLE imported__from_csv ( .. , @datetime_variable, .. )
..
SET .. ,
    datetime_column = STR_TO_DATE( @datetime_variable, '%d-%m-%Y'),
    .. ;
```

I.e. we load the value which has incorrect format into user-defined variable, then we convert the value to correct date literal, and finally we save the value into the table.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I suspect simply loading it, and then converting it will be both quicker and simpler.

Comment: @Strawberry No. 1) This convertion during data load does not affect (more precisely the difference is not detectable) the time needed for importing. 2) Additional column needs to be deleted additionally - and this needs in additional time.